# Nginx Dynamic Proxy

Tags: nginx

Hi I want to setup a dynamic proxy for nginx..

```
location /X/Y{
    proxy_pass   http://X:Y;
    proxy_redirect          off;
    proxy_next_upstream     error timeout invalid_header http_500;
    proxy_connect_timeout   1;
    }
```

now when a user make a request

"'http://com.mypc/com.test/8181" the nginx nee to redirect it to "http://com.test:8181"

Please help me so that i could resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to write nginx load-balancer module. 
`ngx_http_upstream_ip_hash_module.c` does something similar, so you may want to start off from it.

Nginx module writing guide: http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html